# Help understanding how to move coin

Tags: etherscan

I participated in the now defunct Envion coin ICO. I really had a hard time figure out the transfer of coins, where my wallet was, and the basics of coins in general. I did not expect it to be so involved and was overwhelmed. Its safe to say I do not understand the basics of Crypto like i thought i did. So now two years on from Envions collapse I am filing with the Swiss AG that is liquidating their assets. I am trying now to move my coins to the ag and have hit a wall. The only thing the ICO (envion) provided me when i signed up was a Etherscan wallet that shows my 1500 some env coins. they told me its an unlocked wallet but it seems like etherscan is not a wallet and is just a way to verify contracts? again I'm pretty much totally lost but what I do know is envion said "you unlocked wallet is here" and linked me to a ethscan page.. Can anyone shine some light on what I'm not understanding?

Comment: Did you provide the ICO with your ethereum address? Did the 'etherscan wallet' link they sent you look like this: https://etherscan.io/address/0x818488562386ff0d6319c3389c9ee158b0fe26d9 or differently?

Answer (score 1):

> Etherscan is not a wallet and is just a way to verify contracts

1. Etherscan is indeed not a wallet
2. Etherscan is indeed a service which allows you to verify a contract by sending its source code (to Etherscan)
3. Etherscan is a lot more than "just a way to verify contracts" - it allows many more things; you may consider it as an explorer of the Ethereum blockchain

> They told me its an unlocked wallet

A wallet can be unlocked on a given node in the Ethereum blockchain network, which means that anyone who can connect to this node, can also send transactions from that wallet without the need of its private key; It is therefore not a recommend method for one to keep their wallet unlocked on a node, which implies that your wallet was most likely **not unlocked** anywhere (and you wouldn't want that either)

> Envion said "your unlocked wallet is here" and linked me to an Etherscan page

That sounds like an outright lie to me, but perhaps I am missing their point here (or perhaps you are not communicating it accurately)